# Updating table when user clicks OK button on a JavaScript alert

Tags: javascript, php, triggers

So, I have a PHP that will echo a JavaScript `alert()` message when a record is inserted on a table.

Also, I have a trigger JavaScript for triggering the PHP in a given time.
Here is my code for trigger JavaScript:

```
/*refresh every 1 minute*/
setInterval(function () {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'check.php', 
        success: function (result) {
            // console.log(result);
            alert('Another ticket from API');
        }
    });
}, 1000);
```

Here is a sample of my PHP:

```
$query="SELECT TOP(1)* FROM tblname WHERE Status=0";
$que=mssql_query($query);
if($que>0){
    echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('Record inserted on a table')    </script";
}
```

So what I want is when an `alert()` message pop-up is displayed and the user clicks OK, the `Status=0` in the table will be updated to `Status=1` so it won't show again.

Any idea how to do this?

Comment: In success function you call the query by which table is populated and refresh the page or only the table.

Answer (score 1):

You can have multiple lines in your `<script>`, right? First line would call alert, second would call your PHP to update the database.

```
if($que>0){
    echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('Record inserted on a table'); callDatabaseToUpdateStatusToZero();  </script";
}
```

Here `callDatabaseToUpdateStatusToZero()` would be a JavaScript function that makes a call to a PHP file to update the status.

Comment: is callDatabaseToUpdateStatusToZero() a function?so i will put the php for update in () right?